# Are boxed PC retail copies of Skyrim region-locked?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, region-lock, drm

I've heard that all PC copies of Skyrim require Steam activation and am wondering if this is forcing region locking. I want to buy a UK copy of Skyrim and be able to activate/play it in the USA. Can this be done without modifying the game?

Comment: All I can find is that boxed versions of the game -are- region locked (and so are just about every version of the game really as they all come back to Steam keys).. but no one really answers the question of can you play a game targeted at region A while being at region B (though most of the questions are about people in non-english speaking countries preferring the non-translated version of the game due to how crappy and inconsistent most translations are).

Answer (score 3):

I am located in India, and the only way I could purchase the retail edition was a version that is imported. All imported editions of Skyrim in the Indian market available are imported from the UK under license.

But the actual retail box does not display the license, the importer's packaging displays the license number of import.

I also have friends who have purchased Skyrim while on business in the USA. They are able to play Skyrim in India.

But India is not specifically a market where Bethesda officially released the game AFAIK. So do not know if it is considered a "region" in the strict sense. But Steam activation worked for me and my friends.

HTH

Comment: This seems about right. I downloaded my copy online, but I did it from Japan with a US-based VPN (one month release date differential = no thanks). Prior to Japan's official release I had to use the VPN before starting Steam, but now I can have it on or off, that is, be detected in US or Japan. I can also use the Japanese translation. In other words, no region-locking has prevented me from playing the game or using localized content, and I've done about every combination possible that would set off the alarms.